# Download youtube video to user machine on Django website

Tags: python, django, video, download, youtube

Pretty much what the question says. Right now I have this function using pytube:

```py
    def download(request, video_url):
        url='http://www.youtube.com/watch?v='+str(video_url)
        homedir = os.path.expanduser("~")
        dirs = homedir + '/Downloads'
        download = YouTube(url).streams.first().download(dirs)   
        return redirect('../../')
```

But this downloads the video to a directory `/Downloads/` in pythonanywhere - the site that I have uploaded my project to.

How do I download the video to the user's machine? The solution doesn't have to be using the pytube package, as I just want an answer. It will be great if you tell me how to download the file as an `.mp3` file too.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### The issue

When you are running a program on a remote computer (this is your server at pythonanywhere) then all operations happen at that remote computer, not the user's machine.

Therefor, when you download something on a remote computer, it will be downloaded to the remote computer (pythonanywhere).

### A solution

To fulfil your requirements (download a file to the user's computer, not the server), you would probably do something like this:

- Download the file from youtube locally (as you currently do with `YouTube....download()`.
- Send the file to the user. This is what [Gagan Aggarwal's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61201255/532471) is attempting to do with django's `FileResponse`

### Why would this work?

Every time you visit your page in your browser, your django application does roughly the following:

- It receives a request from the user
- It then returns a response

Usually a Django application will return an HTML page. But an HTML page is just a file, and so is your Youtube video that you are downloading. You can choose then to send back the video file instead of a web page. The user's browser will then try to open that file.

### How can I choose the download location?

Your Django application **cannot** choose the download location on the user's computer. This would be a dangerous thing, if any website could just download files on your computer on any location.

However, when you send the file to the user, they can choose where to download it.

If you look at [the documentation for FileResponse](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/request-response/#django.http.FileResponse), you will see that you can pass an `as_attachment=True` parameter.

This will make Django send a file as an "attachment", meaning that it will try to download it and not open it. This will prompt the user to choose the download location of the file.

Comment: Hey, just got back to this solution. The FileResponse redirects me to a page which plays the audio and has a download button but it downloads it to my server too. Is there a way to just redirect to this page without downloading first. If you want me to I can add a picture of the page.

Comment: To make the file available from your server to the browser, you have to "download" it. But that doesn't mean you have to save it in a file and keep it in the server. You can download it in memory or in a temporary file. If you are using `pytube` maybe you can use https://python-pytube.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#pytube.Stream.stream_to_buffer . But you might need to do some reading to understand BinaryIO. For big files you may also want to have a look at Django's StreamingHttpResponse.

Answer (score 1):

I also issued Same Problem but i reduce this problem 80 percent...
So, See the my solution i hope your help this solution :)

first Import Module

```
from django.http import FileResponse
```

Then Code...

```
return FileResponse(open(YouTube(url).streams.first().download(skip_existing=True),'rb'))
```

You can not use return redirect function, you can use FileResponse function

Comment: Hi, and welcome to SO! It may be even more useful if you can explain WHY the poster's original solution doesn't work and this solution does.

Comment: I have no idea for original solution...i trying many time so the solution is already posted.

Comment: I see! I have added a longer answer, I hope you might find this helpful too.

Comment: Hey, just got back to this solution. The FileResponse redirects me to a page which plays the audio and has a download button but it downloads it to my server too. Is there a way to just redirect to this page without downloading first. If you want me to I can add a picture of the page.

Answer (score 0):

I was struggling with this one too. I read what others added here, but that did not work for me.

Then I found the missing piece at [this website](https://nemecek.be/blog/165/django-how-to-let-user-download-a-file). In order to download the file, you have to include `as_attachment=Ture` to the `FileResponse`.

So, The final answer would be as follow:

```py
return FileResponse(open(youtube.download(skip_existing=True),'rb'), as_attachment=True)
```

This will allow the file to get downloaded at the "Downloads" directory on the user's device; not on your pythonanywhere server.

NOTE: the user will stay on this page even after downloading the file.